# Database Design for enterprise hardware stock and billing

Tags: database, database-design

I have to develop a database for an enterprise to manage its **pc hardware and software stocks, PC breakdowns and pc assignment to users.**

I'm a beginner to database design* so I'd like some advice on how to model the database properly from scratch.

I've already done some research and started something, but since you guys are experts, I'd like your take on it, please.

Details are not important, what I need is to know **what tables you would make, and their relationships.**

**I've included a screenshot of the ERD I've come up with. Please have a look.**

[image: ER Diagram]

Here is what's I've done so far. I know it may be poorly design, keep in mind it's a first for me.

1. Basically, I have a list of users.

   - let's go for a user table.
2. Each user can have many pcs (but one pc for one user only).

   - so, PC table, with FK to users.
3. A PC consists of many types of identified hardware from a set list of MB, CPU, HDDs, RAM, GFX cards.

   - Here I made a category table for hard type (cpu, gfx, etc..)
   - Then make and model tables.
   - Finally a mode detail table to store all sorts of details like frequencies, sizes, etc..
   - I link those tables to a hardware table with FKs in it to have a mix giving me a piece of hardware. 
     ---> I know there must be a way to link the table in muck better/proper/efficient manner there!
4. I want to be able to display the PC user/hardware given from a set list and track the hardware via its billings.

   - So I make a hardware stock table. I link one hardware to many hardware stocked with FK in hardware_stock table and its billing.
5. I can track failures/breakdowns for each PCs.

   - there's a failure type table. And I link it to PC via an intersecting table failure event containing FKs to pc_id and failure_type_id.
   - then I keep comments in a separated table linked to failure_event.

So there it is. **I've not tackled the software management yet**.
Basically, it's the same than hardware, I have a set list of different software and:

- I want to know what's installed on the PCs.
- I want to know the billings and license attached to the software stocks.

Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two options:

1. Add tables "software", "publisher", "software_category"; add a link table similar to "pc_hardware".
2. Change 'hardware' to "component", and add 'Software' as a component category.

Option 1 adds more tables, but is more distinct; managing software licences may be easier with this approach.

Option 2 has fewer tables, but is a little harder to understand. Under this approach, a software licence could be a type of 'product warranty' (but that feels messy!)

Just out of interest, have you investigated any open-source or COTS products that do asset management and issue tracking? I have no idea if there are any products available, but you can't be the first person/enterprise to want to do this sort of thing!

Comment: I hadn't thought about investigating open source asset managers, and I did out of your suggestion. I looked at OpenAudit a bit, and this conforted me that I hadn't made 'fundamentals big' mistakes. I think I'll go for option no 1. different tables for soft and hard. Much more tables, but in the end I think it's a bit more managable this way. Thanks for the tips btw.

Answer (score 1):

Your relationships are a bit much for me to go through.

Here's how you can check your own ERD.  Using pencil and index cards, write down the screen fields of your proposed system screens and the report fields of your proposed system reports.

Something like this:

```
Add a new PC
------------
PC name
PC network
User
...
```

One index card per screen and report.

If you wish, you can sketch out the appearance of the screens and reports.

Once you've done this for every screen and report you can imagine, you can map your paper screens to your paper database (ERD).  If you can easily imagine (code) the select, insert, update, and delete SQL for yor paper database, then your design is good.

Comment: I'm not sure t get you: you're saying I should go sort of 'view' logic when designing my db? Their relationships should be based on the way the data will be shown? Because I just linked tables only thinking about their 'real world' relations, thinking that was the only matter. And i was thinking of implementing this 'view' logic in the code, some sort of view logic oriented models, that would handle the complicated view stuff if any.

Comment: @user2728706: No, I'm not saying your database should look like the "view".  What I am saying is describing the "view" will help you discover missing columns, like dates and date-times, and test your relationships.